# Restarting SQLService when application freezes

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

I have a weird issue. I have a application developed with Microsoft Visual Fox Pro with odbc connection to my Server, SQL Server 2017. This application creates locally database .db to increase the performance.

The issue:
Every morning, the first cashier login to system in approximately 2 minutes maximum, the others takes too long to log and to solve the problem, I need to restart the SQL Server Service.  Any idea what this happens?

Comment: The last official update to FoxPro was in 2007, mainstream support ended in 2010 and extended support ended in 2015. Consider replacing your application.

Comment: The fact that the SQL Server instance needs restarting suggests that your application is leaving a transaction or something open and not properly closed/committed, thus when another `USER`/`LOGIN` attempts to access the data that transaction is holding, it is blocked and waits until it is released (which never occurs). This, of course, is a complete guess, as we have no actual details on the problem other than the scenario.

Comment: Hummm good feedback even it is guessing. Now, why this kind of application needs to create db locally  ? to improve performance  ?

Comment: "*why this kind of application needs to create db locally*" - Unlikely anyone here can answer this question because of two reasons: 1. FoxPro is a dead technology; 2. We didn't create the application. As previously mentioned, you should look to replace your application. If Larnu's guess is correct there's probably not much else you can do, as it is the application causing the issue. You should reach out to the vendor to see if they've released a later version using an actual modern database system, or at least a fix for this issue.

Comment: It is not VFP's fault. You shouldn't be using SQL server local db with VFP or any other language. Why would you ever want to use local db in a multiuser environment? Instead you could use MS SQL Server express, or postgreSQL, or MySQL ... We have applications working on hundreds of server and client machines using SQL server and we don't have any problem. People erronously blame VFP when such things happen.

Comment: The VFP application uses SQLServer but creates locally db also,  I guess to improve performance of application in that computer where is executing.  Thanks all comments,  helped a lot.

Comment: @AndersonMuniz, doing such wouldn't increase performance but just make things complicated. Then instead of SQL server local db, you could use say SQLite or simply native VFP tables. But as I said, such approach makes things complicated. I have done that with SQLite (caching locally with change tracking enabled on SQL server) and SQL server but gain was negligible. Managing it is harder and not worth doing it IMHO.